# Posterior distribution for multivariate Gamma-Normal model

Tags: gamma-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, conjugate-prior, inverse-gamma-distribution

Let $\theta \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n$ be a random variable with prior distribution $p(\theta)$:
\begin{equation}
p(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \text{Ga}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)(\theta_i),
\end{equation}
where $\text{Ga}(\alpha_i, \beta_i)$ denotes the Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$. If needed, we can assume that the parameters $\alpha$s and $\beta$s are equal.

We consider a conditionally normal likelihood for the scalar random variable $y \in \mathbb{R}$, i.e,
$y|\theta \sim p(y | \theta) = \mathcal{N}(0, 1 + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i)$

The joint distribution $p(y, \theta)$ reads
\begin{equation}
\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i \right) \exp \left(-\frac{y^2}{2(1 + \sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i)}\right) \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\beta^\alpha \theta_i^{\alpha - 1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \exp \left(-\beta \theta_i \right)
\end{equation}

What is the posterior distribution $p(\theta | y)$? Does it belong to a known family of distributions?

Comment: Are you asking if this model is a “conjugate prior”? Aka closed form solution. There exist some conjugate priors but most often you’ll need a sampler for Bayesian inference - try Stan or PyMC

Comment: Here’s a list of conjugate priors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior in this case, yes one exists.

Comment: Thank you @jbuddy_13 for your reply. I want to know if this posterior belongs to a known class of distributions. Can we compute the marginal $p(y)$?I don't see this case treated in your reference, as we have a multi-dimensional prior for the parameter $\theta$.